# RSpec: Is there a way to check for a nested hash key at any level?

Tags: rspec

I expect my hash to look like one of these two:

```
{metadata: {SOME_UNKNOWN_KEY: {transaction_id: 123456}}}
{metadata: {transaction_id: 123456}}
```

If I'm looking for the key `:transaction_id`, I understand that I can use `hash_including` to expect a nested key that should be in a particular place, but I'd like to be able to do something like this to cover both options:

```
expect(something).
  to receive(some_method).
  with(hash_including(metadata: hash_including_anywhere(:transaction_id)))
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible!

Looking at how `hash_including` is implemented one can see that it's a simple matcher class there:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/lib/rspec/mocks/argument_matchers.rb#L70

`HashIncluding` matcher is based on `BaseHashMatcher` and it looks like if you played with some recursive approach to check if there's the key hiding somewhere deeper you should be good to go:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/lib/rspec/mocks/argument_matchers.rb#L183

You can start from reading the specs for `hash_including` to get yourself started: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/spec/rspec/mocks/hash_including_matcher_spec.rb

Defining your own matcher sounds scary because they work like magic in our tests, but they are actually not that complicated to write.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to actually put this into practice yet, but this definitely looks like the right direction. Thanks!